# Keras evaluate generator progress

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, keras

I'm using Keras to train an image classification network (using the standalone version - not the one included TensorFlow since it doesn't have Inception ResNet v2 yet).

I'm using `evaluate_generator` to evaluate the network results on about 20,000 images but it takes a long time to run (a few minutes). Is there a way to output the progress while it's running? Couldn't find anything about this in the documentation or in Google results.

Comment: Seems they just forgot to add the feature as evaluate has the verbose parameter which adds the progress bar. There is an issue about it: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/5355